# Update Entity Data Model After Tree Drag and Drop

Tags: wpf, database, devexpress

I have a Dev-express Tree Structure with Drag and Drop capability. After Drag and Drop there is always a new structure of my database because change in the Tree structure. I want to update by database as soon as I apply Drag and Drop inside my Tree.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you applying drop event, handle it right way and that is. It will look like this:

```
public void TreeView_Droped (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Do some work
    UpdateMyDataSource(sender, e, [another_fields_you_need]);
}
```

In `UpdateMyDataSource()` you have to invoke your own logic to update database entity[ies] (connect to database, blah blah blah, etc.). You can retrive object you need using your own casting on `sender` or `e` objects.